# How to delay sign a precompiled C# exe using .snk public key

Tags: c#-4.0

Actually my problem is I only have the generated *.exe of C# code and one public key through which i have to generate delay sign builds after which the owner of private key can sign it. The links we have provided talks about using AL i think which requires *.cs file as well. but i dont have any access to code and wants the builds to be delay signed.

Can anyone help me with that?